# $H\otimes K$ isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{i\in I}K$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces. Suppose $H$ is separable (could be finite/infinite dimensional).

As Hilbert spaces, are $H\otimes K$ and $\bigoplus_{i\in I} K$ isomorphic? Here $I$ is an index set for a countable orthonormal basis for $H$ and isomorphic means existence of a unitary map $U$.

**A guess**  If $\{e_i\}$ is a countable orthonormal basis for $H$, consider the extension of the mapping defined by $e_i\otimes k\mapsto [ \overbrace{0\ \cdots\ 0}^{i-1}\ k\ 0\ \cdots]$ for all $i$ and $k\in \mathcal{K}$.

If the answer is yes, and say $H$ is not separable now, does the isomorphism still hold?

Comment: It won't be true if $\dim H=\infty$ and you use the usual "algebaic" tensor product; you have to define $H\otimes K$ as a Hilbert space tensor product (the metric completion of the "algebraic" one), and then the statement is true for separable Hilbert spaces (you also need Hilbert space direct sums, not the usual "algebraic" direct sums). For non-separable Hilbert spaces, I imagine you need to use direct integrals instead of direct sums...

Comment: Here, I’m viewing the tensor to be the Hilbert space completion of the algebraic tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes, even without separability assumptions. Here the direct sums and tensor products are all in the category of Hilbert spaces, so these are completions of their algebraic counterparts.

Let $\{e_i: i \in I\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Then
\begin{align}H \otimes K &= \left(\bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{C}e_i\right)\otimes K\\
&\cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} (\mathbb{C}e_i \otimes K)\\
&\cong  \bigoplus_{i \in I}K\end{align}

What you need to check: that tensor products distribute over direct sums. More precisely, show that there is a canonical unitary
$$U: \bigoplus_{i \in I} (H_i \otimes K) \to  \left(\bigoplus_{i \in I}H_i \right)\otimes K.$$

**Hint**: Show that the canonical isomorphism between their algebraic counterparts is isometric. Then, invoke the universal property of completion to extend this map and invoke a density argument to show surjectivity.

Comment: Thanks I’ll have to parse this out in a moment. but do you think my guess unitary works?

Comment: @chhro I think it might. It looks like your mapping coincides with the composition of the natural isomorphisms in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I would have preferred an explicit unitary because I wanted to experiment with its effect on certain vectors. I will have to think about your answer for the meantime but I did accept your answer.